# Classpath error in spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Hello guys please help me out with this error when I run my spring boot app this error pops out. I tried the suggested action but still not working.

Dependency

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

```
org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.processComplementaryTableDefinitions(EntityBinder.java:1238)
```

The following method did not exist:

```
javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
```

The method's class, javax.persistence.Table, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/INTEL/Desktop/timetablesystem/lib/javax.persistence.jar!/javax/persistence/Table.class
jar:file:/C:/Users/INTEL/.m2/repository/jakarta/persistence/jakarta.persistence-api/2.2.3/jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar!/javax/persistence/Table.class
```

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

```
javax.persistence.Table: file:/C:/Users/INTEL/Desktop/timetablesystem/lib/javax.persistence.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of javax.persistence.Table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `C:/Users/INTEL/Desktop/timetablesystem/lib/javax.persistence.jar` from the classpath of your application as it contains an old version of the Java Persistence API that is incompatible with the version of Spring Boot that you're using. Exactly how that should be done depends on how you're running your application.

Comment: I am using Intellij IDE